# R cannot be resolved to a variable?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I cleaned my project and now I get a "R cannot be resolved to a variable." It was fine before I cleaned it.

I have tried cleaning it again, building the project again, creating a new project and copying all my files over, and I've gone to the Android SDK Manager and installed all the "Android SDK  Build-tools" to Install all the options like the other stackoverflow posts have mentioned: [image]

Can anyone suggest anything?

[image]

The above picture shows my generated files and lack of an R.java file.

[image: When I check the Problems]

The above picture shows my problems log.

Comment: try window ->show view -> other -> General -> problem , and search in this tab on your project you will the error why it can't  generate the R file

Comment: An error in an XML file can cause this issue. Be sure to double check all XML file names (all lower case letters and must start with a letter) and the contents for a syntax error.

Comment: @mohammedmomn I added a screenshot of my General -> Problem

Comment: Make sure that all your images are lower case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure R is in the same package as the file where you want to call it from.
(or import the package in the source file)

To change the package of the R file open your App Manifest file and change packge="" to the same package as where your source files are in.

[image: eclipse-image]

Comment: It's the same (see above, I added a screenshot)

Comment: Uh sorry.
But your R.java file is clearly not existing.
Have you tried just deleting the package in gen/ ?
If your IDE doesn't rebuild that package (including the R file) I suspect you have an error in a xml file.

Comment: yes, when I try to clean, it does not build the R.java file.

Comment: Do you have an error in a xml file ?
For me eclipse sometimes doesn't highlight xml errors like it does with errors in code.
Try to restart eclipse and/or look in the console.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you import take other thing

See package main import in your code
should be like this
example:

```
import com.mypackageprincipal.R;
```

other import of R delete only should exist it

and after clean and build your project

Comment: If I do the import statement, then along with other new errors, it states my activity_main "cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: also u can create new project wiht activity of same name and after take files .java and your AndroidManifest.xml also your folder name res if you have files of your old project and overwrite on new and compile